# Group By Order By returning wrong column - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, chat

I have this table:

| msg_id | msg | from_user | to_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello! | 16 | 77 |
| 2 | Wassup? | 16 | 77 |
| 3 | Hey there! | 77 | 16 |
| 4 | Hola! | 7 | 77 |

I want to group these messages in descending order while taking 77 as current user, like this:

| msg_id | msg | other_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Hola! | 7 |
| 3 | Hey there! | 16 |

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN from_user = 77 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END) AS other_user, 
       MAX(msg_id) as id, 
       msg 
FROM chat_schema 
WHERE 77 IN (from_user, to_user) 
GROUP BY other_user 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This is the result of following query:

| id | msg | other_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Hola! | 7 |
| 3 | Hello! | 16 |

For some reason, the ids are correct but the message does not match up with that id (id 3 message is 'Hey there' but it's returning 'Hello!' which is id 1). It is fetching the first message of each group instead of the message from that particular id. How to fix this?

Comment: if you select values that are not in group by, the result is not defined

Comment: Select only `MAX(msg_id)`. Then, using it, select `msg` from another table copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all the questions and answers mentioned, I assume there might be many users interacting with User 77.
I have presumed you want the last conversation(either sent or received) with User 77:

Please do try the following query and let me know how it goes with you:

```
SELECT 
maxMsgId,
msg,
(CASE WHEN from_user=77 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END) AS otherUser
FROM (
SELECT MAX(cs.`msg_id`) AS maxMsgId
FROM 
`chat_schema` cs 
WHERE cs.`from_user`=77 OR cs.`to_user`=77
 GROUP BY 
 LEAST(cs.`from_user`, cs.`to_user`), 
 GREATEST(cs.`from_user`, cs.`to_user`)) 
 primarySelect
 JOIN `chat_schema` c ON primarySelect.maxMsgId=c.`msg_id`
 ORDER BY c.`msg_id` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes this is exactly what I want. But I am not sure which provides better performance between yours and @forpas 's answer.

Comment: Let your indexing and MySQL's optimizer take care of that. If you really want to know the difference try both queries and see for yourself which works better for you. What version of MySQL are you using by the way?

Comment: The server version is 5.7.34.

Comment: In that case, the window function is of no use to you. You've gotta try between my query and forpa's second query. Please do choose your preference. *EDIT* I have edited my answer to remove unnecessary selects

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to get the last message (sent, received) by a specific user, you may try the following:

```
Select C.msg_id, C.msg, 
       Case
           When C.from_user=77 Then C.to_user
           Else C.from_user
       End as other_user, D.other_user_type
From
    (
      Select Max(msg_id) as mid, 'R' as other_user_type From chat_schema
      Where from_user=77
      Union All
      Select Max(msg_id), 'S' From chat_schema
      Where to_user=77
     ) D
Join chat_schema C
On D.mid = C.msg_id
```

I added an extra column `other_user_Type` to specify the `other_user` type (sender or receiver), you may remove it from the result set.

See a demo from [*db_fiddle*](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o55GrqUeLywagKJvm1UJPb/0).

***Update*** to select the last conversations a user had:

```
Select C.msg_id, C.msg, C.from_user, C.to_user
From
    ( 
      Select u1, u2, Max(m) mid 
      From
      ( 
        Select from_user u1, to_user u2, msg_id m From chat_schema
        Where from_user = 77
        Union All
        Select to_user, from_user, msg_id From chat_schema
        Where to_user = 77
      ) D
     Group By u1, u2
    ) F
Join chat_schema C
On F.mid = C.msg_id
```

See a demo from [*db-fiddle*](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5rcPVUKy3LhXMyJsVvafrq/1).

Comment: Perfect! Any comments on performance?

Comment: I think it will perform well, especially if the table is well indexed. Performance tuning requires you to check the execution plan of the query.

Comment: Ahmed all of a sudden when there are new entries, the results are not returning as expected. The users are not grouped. What went wrong?

Comment: @WebDiva, can you create a fiddle to show where is the problem with this query? This query returns the last two messages (sent, received) by a specific user, is that what you need?

Comment: No not the last two messages but the last few conversations that the current user had. Your query worked the first time but when I added two more records, it returns the same ```other_user``` messages twice.  Here is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oK7QmufggmvZ3sQ24KXCn2/0 . You can see that user 16 returns twice.

Comment: @WebDiva,  I thought that you need that last two only, and I wrote that in the answer at the first time, anyway I'll fix that.

Comment: @Ahmed, you are using unnecessary union in order to provide the OP. Use `Explain` before your query, you'll see that it will be an expensive query in the long run

Comment: @Asgar, It's a necessary union, in the 1st, select `from_user, to_user` and in the 2nd select `to_user, from_user`. It's a work around to select the last message sent Or received by a user. The `Group By` will eliminate one of (sent, received) messages if both are existed.

Comment: @Ahmed, did you see the query execution plan using your query?

Answer (score 7):

For MySql 8.0+ use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY CASE WHEN from_user = 77 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END 
           ORDER BY msg_id DESC
         ) rn
  FROM chat_schema
  WHERE 77 IN (from_user, to_user)
)
SELECT msg_id, msg, from_user, to_user
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY msg_id DESC;
```

For previous versions use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT cs1.*
FROM chat_schema cs1
WHERE 77 IN (cs1.from_user, cs1.to_user)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM chat_schema cs2
            WHERE (cs2.from_user, cs2.to_user) IN ((cs1.from_user, cs1.to_user), (cs1.to_user, cs1.from_user))
              AND cs2.msg_id > cs1.msg_id
          )
ORDER BY cs1.msg_id DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c4064fc6f9a9087d09a8af6b1de956b).

Answer (score 2):

i have find max ids with group by than use in where condition

```
select msg_id, msg,
(CASE WHEN from_user = 77 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END) as other_user
from chat_schema 
where msg_id in (select 
Max(msg_id) as id
from chat_schema
where 77 IN (from_user, to_user)
group by (CASE WHEN from_user = 77 THEN to_user ELSE from_user END))
order by msg_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is quite identical in (CASE/IF) but semplified.
Perhaps your query is a bit weird.
Try to see without LIMIT 2 what happens

```
SELECT IF(from_user=77, to_user, from_user) AS other_user, id, msg 
FROM chat_schema
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thank you. But this does not actually group the users.